# How to send a mock webhook with body from Wiremock response body

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I try to create a mock webhook request, which will be triggered when request `/transform` is call
in webhook request body will get the id from response body id. How can I achieve that?

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/transform"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{\"message\": \"success\", \"id\": \"{{randomValue length=10 type='ALPHANUMERIC'}}\"}",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  },
  "serveEventListeners": [
    {
      "name": "webhook",
      "parameters": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "https://webhook.site/9c32fadb-b542-4edf-a530-85a012064566",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{\"id\": \"{{jsonPath response.body '$.id'}}\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd try with body-transformer, but still not able to get the id value from response

```
"transformers":[  
            "body-transformer"
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This conversation was had on the Wiremock community slack here - https://wiremock-community.slack.com/archives/C03NAEH5LVA/p1705654286090779

The answers are replicated here for completeness:

The response object is not available in the templating system for webhooks.  From looking at the [documentation](https://wiremock.org/docs/webhooks-and-callbacks/) it seems you can only use the original request in the templating of the webhook payload:

```json
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/webhooks"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
      "message": "success",
      "transactionId": "{{jsonPath request.body '$.id'}}"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  },
  "serveEventListeners": [
    {
      "name": "webhook",
      "parameters": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "http://host.docker.internal:7070/callback-logger/api/callback",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{\"systemId\": \"{{jsonPath originalRequest.body '$.id'}}\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Request body:

```json
{
  "id": "1234567890"
}
```

At the moment the only way to simulate what you are looking for is to send in the value as a value in the request body (as above) or as a request
header in your test.  That way the value will be available in the response and webhook.

This isn't ideal and we do have an issue raised to address this - https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/2359